# Calling PHP Code from Function?

Tags: wordpress, require

I am very new to PHP. As a graphic designer it is hard for us to conceptualize PHP and back-end codes to do what we envision, so please go easy on me. :) It doesn't come naturally to people like me.

I have a block of code that I want to call into my theme in the efforts of minimalizing the front-end.

```
<title>
<? global $page, $paged; wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); bloginfo( 'name' );
  $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
  if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
    echo " | $site_description";
  if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
    echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'framework' ), max( $paged, $page ) );?>
</title>
```

I need to make it cleaner. Example:

```
<title>
  <? require(TEMPLATEPATH . '/library/clean.php', 'FUNCTION_NAME_TO_CALL')
</title>
```

1. Am I able to place the code within  directly into a function?
2. Am I able to require() the clean.php and tell that require() to only
   use a specific function? If so how?

If my logic in doing this is wrong then please let me know, I am eager to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
<title><?php myTitle(); ?></title>
```

Declare the `myTitle()` function in your `themes_folder/functions.php` file like this:

```
// In functions.php
function myTitle()
{
    // Put the code here...
}
```

Note: I've use `myTitle()` as function name but you may use anything as you like.

Comment: 1. Am I able to place the code within `<title>` directly into the `function myTitle()`? 2. Am I able to `require()` the `clean.php` and tell that `require()` to only use a specific function? If so how?

Comment: One last question. In efforts to bullet-proof Wordpress my functions.php file has 10 requires in it that point the library. I do not want Wordpress to be updated and my functions file wiped (has happened previously). How can I still use `<? myTitle(); ?>` and call the function this way? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: If you update the `WordPress` then the `functions.php` will remain the same, i run a blog using `WordPress` and regularly update it without any problem.

Comment: That is good to know. This happened to me a few years back, I've been wary every since. Might have been an error of my own, though. Still, for the sake of knowledge on the topic, would I still be able to call this function even if my functions.php require other php files elsewhere in, say, the `library` directory? Thanks in advance, not trying to be obsessive with this :)

Comment: Since this function is inside your `functions.php` file then it's available everywhere in the script and you may use `include/require` as well, `include/require` is just like copy and pasting the code.

Answer (score 1):

Start by getting the PHP syntax correct.  You need need semi-colon at the end of your require line and then close the PHP code block.

```
<? require(TEMPLATEPATH . '/library/clean.php'); ?>
```

Then, as someone mentioned, you can call your specific functions.  Assuming clean.php has a function called 'getTitle'...

```
<title><?php getTitle() ?></title>
```

Comment: For the sake of quickly posting I did not worry about syntax. However in development I use a PHP checker and make sure my HTML and PHP syntax is perfect. :P Sorry for not doing so beforehand, I was only trying to get the concept across.

Comment: Alright.  I think I jumped on this question thinking you had something setup and it just wasn't working.  You were just trying to get the concept.

Comment: Correct. Though for future reference I should probably make sure it has correct syntax before posting. Lol. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Write the code as a function in the theme's `functions.php` file.  So you put

```
function cleanTitle() {
   global $page, $paged; wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); bloginfo( 'name' );
   $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
   if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
      echo " | $site_description";
   if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
      echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'framework' ), max( $paged, $page ) );?>
}
```

into the `functions.php` file and `<?php cleanTitle() ?>` into your page template.